# Mock angular2 service in protractor tests

Tags: angular, protractor

I'd like to effectively provide an alternate implementation of an angular2 service for the extent of the protractor test spec. I'm not trying to test the service, so MockBackend provides little value.

Is there anyway I can access injector or register a provider before specs run? this type of thing

```
{provide: MyService, useClass: MyMockedService}
```

And just have MyMockedService have same methods that return hardcoded values?

I know how to do this in unit tests, this is specifically protractor e2e tests. And again, I'm not trying to test the service... I dont believe MockBackend helps here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different environment for your protractor tests and then add a check for it in the module where the service is registered. With an abstract super class, you can then use DI in Angular to inject different value depending on the environment. Similar like this:

```
environment.e2eMode ? {provide: AbstractService, useClass: ServiceMock} : {provide: AbstractService, useClass: ServiceImpl},
```

But you have to take care your MockService does not end up in production code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of / tried [ng-Apimock](https://github.com/mdasberg/ng-apimock). I use this for a customer that builds an Angular 2+ application and it works fine. It is used for local development (there's a simple UI to select different scenario's per service) and use it during Protractor tests. It's easy to create responses and you can use globals that are defined on the fly.

It can be used with different configurations (Angular cli, Angular Seed, grunt, gulp, ..).

Hope it helps.